# flashing text issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that makes text alternate between a specific color and grey. It blinks every second or so between the two colors. My code for it is this:

### HTML bit

```
<script>
  setInterval(function() {
    flashtext('flashingtext','<? echo $name_color ?>');
     }, 500 );
   </script>

<span id="flashingtext" style="color: <? echo $name_color ?>"><? echo $name ?></span>
```

### JavaScript

```
function flashtext(ele,col) {
var tmpColCheck = document.getElementById( ele ).style.color;
   if (tmpColCheck === 'gray') {
      document.getElementById( ele ).style.color = col;
      } else {
      document.getElementById( ele ).style.color = 'gray';
      }
   }
```

The problem I have with this is that the section of the page that runs the HTML is refreshed every 10 seconds. This results in the timing of the blinking being messed up. It'll start blinking like I said every second, then when that page section refreshes it'll blink really fast and continue unless the whole page is manually refreshed again.

Any idea how to stop this? Figure the timer isn't getting reset or something... Or when its grabbing the current color it catches it on gray? Not sure :s

Comment: add servertime to the javascript function and sync the blinking with it

Comment: thanks, not really sure how to go about that

Comment: Life was so much easier with [`<blink>`](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2046054/the-blink-tag-is-finally-dead-killed-off-by-firefox-23.html)

Comment: @Rhumborl Use a couple CSS3 transitions and you can recreate blink without JavaScript. :)

Comment: FYI There is no such thing as a 'jQuery function'. That is a JavaScript function. On top of that, I see no jQuery used on your code snippet(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It keeps getting faster because you keep adding the timer. So add a check to see if it is defined and cancel it.

```
<script>
    if (typeof flashTimer !== "undefined") {
       window.clearTimeout(flashTimer);
    }
    flashTimer = setInterval( function() {
        flashtext('flashingtext','<? echo $name_color ?>');
     }, 500 );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

By time synchronization I mean using server time for the animation:

```
this.onload = function(){
        var ts0 = <?=round(microtime(true)*1000);?>;
        var dt = new Date()-ts0;
        var blink = function(){
            console.log(Math.ceil((new Date()-dt)/1000)%2);
            requestAnimationFrame(blink);
        }
        blink();
    }
```

This way anytime you refresh the page, the blinking remains consistent.